# Listener only for the first click on JTextField

Tags: java

Is there a java event for JTextField do like :
if the cursor already was in the JTextField and MousePressed = do nothing
if click on the JTextField for the first time = do things
I have been used , `MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)` but this not exactly what I want.
thank you

Comment: `MousePressed` is correct event. You just have to perform the described checks each time the listener is triggered. So basically check if the textfield has focus or not

Comment: so as long as the mouse is over the `JTextField`, it will do nothing on the second (and subsequent) clicks? i dont think there is out-of-the-box event for that. but you might be able to use some flags and other events to get the behaviour you wanted (e.g. after the first click set a flag, then on exit remove the flag).

Comment: @XtremeBaumer im beginner can you tell me how i can check it , or i should change my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own custom logic:

- Store a "flag" like global boolean variable:

  ```
  boolean alreadyClicked = false
  ```
- Each time you click the JTextField check (and toggle) that variable:

  ```
  if(!alreadyClicked) {
     alreadyClicked = true;
    // do your work
  }
  ```
- When focusing out from that field toggle variable again to:

  ```
  alreadyClicked = false;
  ```